# get filename of extended class

Tags: php, class

Let's say I have two files, each one has a class. How can I get the filename where the child class is, within the parent class?

File 2 (child class):

```
class B extends A{

}
```

File 1:

```
class A{

  final protected function __construct(){
    // here I want to get the filename where class B is, 
    // or whatever class is the child
  }

}
```

Comment: You want the parent class, to magically know the location of a single arbitrary child class somehow when it's constructed? That is not easily possible, and doesn't really have any purpose. What exactly are you trying to do? There's likely a better way to go about accomplishing your actual end goal.

Comment: How are the classes instantiated with that protected constructor?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not really sure what purpose it serves, but here you go:

```
class A{

  final protected function __construct(){
    $obj = new ReflectionClass($this);
    $filename = $obj->getFileName();
  }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't [ReflectionObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php) be the right choice there?

Comment: You should change the constructor's accessibility to `public`.

Comment: @webbiedave It's hard to tell how the OP's creating objects with that protected constructor but they may have their reasons. Perhaps they have a public, static factory method on `A`

Comment: Well, Phil, I was just backing up your original comment on the OP's question and now you've bamboozled me! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can cheat and use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php):

```
class A {
  final protected function __construct() {
    $stacktrace = @debug_backtrace(false);
    $filename = $stacktrace[0]['file'];
  }
}
```