# Determine what is the file of the function being called

Tags: php, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out where a function is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222142/how-to-find-out-where-a-function-is-defined)
>   [get filename of extended class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364246/get-filename-of-extended-class)

Working on non OO codes in PHP, I sometimes find myself digging through code to find something as simple as "*where that function sits*".

```
function myfunction(){
    where_is_this_function();   
}
```

My question is, how can i find where is the file where the `where_is_this_function()` sits

I know there are debuggers, find in files tools and other options, but i would like to know if there is any programmatic way to do so like, because sometimes it's more handy.

```
get_thefunction_file('where_is_this_function()')
```

Comment: also, debug_backtrace() output sometimes is too confusing for that

Comment: Take a look at [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

Comment: On a sidenote, any decent IDE will allow you to Ctrl+LeftMouse (or other shortcut) on the function to take you there.

Comment: This is the reason you don't use global functions spread across multiple files

Comment: @Stewie yes it'd be awesome if everyone used OO or at least organized their codes well, unfortunately we are not able to choose who's code we mantain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`debug_print_backtrace();`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) in that function it should pretty-print how it was called and from what file

```
function myfunction(){
    debug_print_backtrace();//where_is_this_function();   
}
```

and output a numbered list like

```
#0  myfunction() called at [/tmp/include.php:10]
#1  include(/tmp/include.php) called at [/tmp/test.php:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just concerned about where the function sits while working in the code and don't need the information runtime, development IDEs such as NetBeans or Eclipse have specific "jump to declaration" functionality.

In NetBeans for example you simply place the cursor somewhere within the "where_is_this_functiob" text and press CTRL+B. NetBeans then tries to load the file and jump directly to the function definition.

I'm pretty sure other editors have some similar functionality.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer.
yes, i know there are options, i was just curious about a way to do it code wise :)